# MCEdit still usable? - Transfer old Minecraft buildings to a new world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mcedit

Back then in ~2011/2012 it was pretty usual to use MCEdit to transfer objects into other worlds.

Can you still use this tool? I remember some issues, if you hadn't updated it to the current version of Minecraft, but I saw that the last update of MCEdit was in 2013. My last world got messed up after some time (weird biome-generation and stuff) and I wondered if this may be because of MCEdit.

Or do you have other recommendations? WorldEdit is not an option for me, since my server doesn't run Bukkit. I would like to use an external tool to modify my worlds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually is usable. However, please note that most of the 1.8 blocks have not been implemented yet.
MCEdit Site (Beta build page): http://www.mcedit.net/changes/0.1.8build799.html

[image: Yep. Really broken... And whoops!]
*This is the support for 1.8 blocks in MCEdit; practically close to none.*

[image: The actual map.]
*1.8 works fine.*

---

Alternatively, you can run a locally hosted Bukkit server and install WorldEdit on it.

Comment: MCEdit worked, thank you. Some items like leaves (dunno why leaves... this is nothing new) will appear purple but only in the inventory. All chest items and stuff were transfered sucessfully.
I am NOT sure if WorldEdit would have worked, because Bukkit hasn't been released for 1.8 until now. If you create a new 1.8 world and downgrade it to 1.7 you will lose a lot of blocks I think. So WorldEdit is no option at the moment, if I understood that correctly.

Answer (score 2):

MCEdit was last updated by Codewarrior (the original creator) on the 10th of March with dev build [0.1.8build799](http://www.mcedit.net/changes/0.1.8build799.html). This means that any blocks added since then appear as purple tiles without their proper texture. An image of an acacia fence:

[image]

MCEdit can still place, copy, remove, etc. all of the new tiles no problem. The only issues is that they do not have their proper name or texture, everything else works fine; MCEdit will not replace them with air like Minecraft does if you downgrade.

As MCEdit is opensource, there are also multiple forks that are up to date with all the current tiles. For example, ["MCEdit Unified" by Karthex.](http://khroki.github.io/MCEdit-Unified/)